# Animation issues with KitKat

Tags: android, animation, gradient, android-4.4-kitkat

I am getting complaints from users on Android 4.4.4 about strange rendering issues with my animation. I did not get any complaints from any other Android versions so far. I am also unable to replicate the error in emulator (or on my Nexus 7 which one of the two complaints was using).

I have a complex layout with two fragments. The Fragment with the animation has a ViewFlipper, that contains a Relative Layout with the flashcard object which is being rotated(flipped). The background of the flashcard is a Gradient defined in an XML. It seems that the gradient becomes semi transparent after the animation.

I do not want to post too much code to make the question too unclear. Here are the screenshots from one of the users, that clearly show the issue. If you have any suggestions, please let me know and I will post relevant code/layouts/etc.

This is how the layout should look:

[image: This is how the layout should look]

This is how the layout breaks after the flip animation:

[image: This is how the layout breaks after the flip animation]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the same problem and found this: [Issue 70914](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=70914)
You need to call setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null) for the View that is animated.

Field View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE requires API level 11, so I did it that way:

```
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 11)
    {
        for(View v : rotatedViews)
        {
            v.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }
     }
```

Comment: Thanks. I have found the same article and I have made these changes to my code. I will send it out to the users to test and let you know.